# boost-python pure virtual detecting missing implementation

Tags: c++, boost-python, pure-virtual

I have a C++ class with a pure virtual method exposed to python using boost-python. I am calling the virtual function from C++ and assuming the virtual function is implemented in python. It all works if the function is implemented but if it's not I get a nasty exception.

I am trying to find a way to detect if the method is in fact implemented without calling when I load the class

Roughly the code looks like this

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

public Foo {
public:
   void func() = 0;
}

class PyFoo : public Foo, public boost::python::wrapper<Foo> {
public:
    void func() override {
        get_override("func")();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<PyFoo>, boost::noncopyable>("Foo")
        .def("func", pure_virtual(&PyFoo::func))
        ;
}

void create {
    object main_module = import("__main__");
    object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    std::string overrideCommand(
    R"(
    import example

    class MyFoo(example.Foo):
        def __init__(self):
            example.Foo.__init__(self)

    # virtual function in C++. (Should be defined)
    #    def func(self):
    #        print('func called')
    )");

    boost::python::exec(overrideCommand.c_str(), main_namespace);
    result = eval("MyFoo()", main_namespace);

    // Can I detect if 'result' has func implemented? If I call it and it
    // is not defined death results. I have tried:
    object attr = result.attr("func");

    // but attr always seems to be set even if there is no function,
    // I think from the base class Foo.

    // This is the call:
    Foo& t = extract<Foo&>(result);
    t.func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyCallable_Check](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyCallable_Check).

```
if (!PyCallable_Check(result.func()))
{
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, error_msg.str().c_str());
    python::throw_error_already_set();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to compile exactly so I tried various versions of  this but it always said it's callable even the call crashed. I think the base class is defining a stub that it thinks is callable 'PyObject *callback = PyObject_GetAttrString(result.ptr(), "func"); if (!PyCallable_Check(callback))'

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Workable not elegant. I added the method:

```
bool isThere()  {
    auto obj = get_override("func");
    return PyCallable_Check(obj.ptr());
}
```

to FooPy. Then:

```
FooPy& t = extract<FooPy&>(result);
t.isThere();
```